# Deal with blank row which returns from Comma Separated List To Table Function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

So basically I have a function named as 'CommaSeparatedListToTable'

```
Declare @ID AS Varchar(1000)=''
SELECT item FROM [dbo].[CommaSeparatedListToTable] (@ID)
```

Now when I use that function, my stored procedure looks like this:

```
Select ...
From Table
Where (@ID = '')
       OR (
       @ID <> ''
            AND c.id IN (SELECT item FROM [dbo].[CommaSeparatedListToTable](@ID))
       )
)
```

Here, it returns blank row while passing @ID as blank. But what I wants to do like, instead of dealing with blank row. If it returns a blank row then I want to filter with blank space only.

So something like below,

```
Select ...
From Table
Where (@ID = '')
       OR (
       @ID <> ''
            AND c.id IN ('')
       )
)
```

Comment: can you please provide a sample input and output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this works for you.

```
If exists(SELECT item FROM [dbo].[CommaSeparatedListToTable](@ID))
BEGIN
   Select ...
   From Table
   WHERE c.id IN (SELECT item FROM [dbo].[CommaSeparatedListToTable](@ID)))
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   Select ...
   From Table
   WHERE AND c.id = ' '
END
```